# What is the encoder used by PHP $POST command for audio blob?

Tags: php, audio, encoding, blob

The first sequence of audio samples is recorded in JavaScript from the browser in mono, PCM format, 16-bit, and 96,000 Hz. I wrote this audio file as a blob to a server through a JavaScript FormData object using ajax.

These are the [raw audio samples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx8k9.png) When I retrieved the audio from the web server's directory listing, I received the second sequence of audio samples. It has been downsampled to 48000 Hz and the samples have been altered. What encoder is being used?

Server-side PHP code:

```
    $input = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name']; //audio blob
    $output = $_POST['filename'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($input, $output))
        exit('Audio file Uploaded');
```

Client-side JavaScript code:

```
    function send_audio(fn, blob){

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("filename", fn);
        formData.append('audio', blob);
        $.ajax({
            url:'save_audio.php',
            type:'post',
            data: formData,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("send_audio success!");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: PHP is certainly not touching the audio. I would presume that the final format and encoder are up to the browser... but I could be wrong.

Comment: If it was the browser, it would have affected the first sequence too though.

Comment: PHP does not give a flying hoot about the data you send it, unless you've written code to make it. Your problem is elsewhere. Or maybe it's in the code that you didn't share? Who knows?

Comment: Okay, I've added code. As you can see, I didn't explicitly program it to encode the audio.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... If possible, try to paste any important numbers into your question for checking instead of using a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whats going on but consider the following:

(1) Try **16-bits** not 32-bits per sample (might help).

There is no need to record these audio samples at 32 bits per sample. That means you're using 4 bytes to record one sample value that fits within 2 bytes (16 bits).

Your highest value is `30465` (bytes `x77 x01`) and the lowest value is `-32513` (bytes `x80 xFF`).
Notice those values fit two bytes? By using 4 bytes you make `x00 x00 x77 x01`. A waste to store extra`00`.

Two bytes hold max value of `65535`. Or even `32767` if you divide into two parts as `+32767` and `-32767`.

(2) Make sure there is no confusion between encoding of bytes (as hex), and digits (as integers).

Bytes are written as hex inside a file. Your values seem to mess up when converting from integers into hex format. Also 16 bit vs 32 bits for the

Some examples from your numbers compared to 2 bytes (16-bit) hex:

```
  FIRST SEQ:        SECOND SEQ:
value   | hex       | value   | hex

100       00 64      612        02 64
553       02 29      41         00 29
203       00 CB      -309       FE CB
-409      FE 67      103        00 67
68        00 44      836        03 44
953       03 B9      185        00 B9
154       00 9A      -102       FF 9A
-127      FF 81      385        01 81
```

Notice the value of integer `100` when written as hex (byte values) it becomes byte `x64`, for some reason a `2` is added in front of that `64` now making it `x0264` which converts to integer value of `612`.

In the second sequence, where are these extra `02` and `FE` etc coming from? Why if hex of first seq has a `00`, then for the second seq there's something extra now added? Even vice-versa (first = something, then second = something removed to become as `00`)?

You need to double check your *recording* code. Does it add some increasing number to the recorded value?? Because, as you know, `2` is followed by `3` and that pattern is there in your second sequence. Also true that `FE` is followed by `FF` (and therefore previous to `FE` would be `FD`, `FC`, `FB`, `FA`, etc).

If you still can't explain it then:

- Record at 16-bit with 44,100 Hz like the normal way others do it. Then later get complicated if the simple setup works okay. Why 32-bit and 96,000 Hz anyway? Is it a scientific test?
- Use a Hex Editor to view your bytes from both sides (saved blob file via JS, against file downloaded via PHP) and compare any changes between the two files.
- Show how/what your recording code is doing.
- Share the bytes of *"I retrieved the audio from the web server"* (save as file) for checking.

Maybe someone else can help you. I don't use html forms so maybe there's an encoding option for the `POST` data type in there too?

Comment: This error occurs when storing 16-bit integers as well. I edited the question to reflect this. I will try what you've suggested- thank you.